# GitPython: retrieve changed files between commits in specific sub directory

Tags: python, git, gitpython

The repo structure looks like this:

```
- folder_a
- folder_b
- folder_c
- ...
```

I am particularly interested in the files that changed in a specific commit, but only the ones in *folder_a*. My solution is

```
for filename, details in commit.stats.files.items():
  if not filename.startswith('folder_a'):
     continue
  # ...
```

but it seems the performance is not quite good if there are a great number of files in the other folders. Is there any better way to skip the files I don't care about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly : you want stats on modifications from a commit, only on one specific subfolder.

Using plain git :

```
git show [commit] --stat folder_a
```

will display exactly what you want.

Have a look at what : `git.show('<commit identifier>', '--stat', 'folder_a');` returns in your python script.